# Entity Framework Create a left outer join that only pulls in the last record

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, left-join

I searched on my particular question and found several close questions, but none that helped after much experimentation.

Given the following code:

```
var results = context.Shipments.AsNoTracking().Where(x => customerIds.Contains(x.CustomerId.Value) && x.ProcessStageFlag == ProcessStage.Complete)
  .GroupJoin(context.Audit.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Action != null), 
    sh => new { im.Shipments.TrackingNumber, im.Shipments.InvoiceNumber },
    au => new { rn.TrackingNumber, rn.InvoiceNumber },
    (sh, au) => new { Shipments = sh.Shipments, Audit = au })
  .SelectMany(x => x.Audit.DefaultIfEmpty(),
    (x, y) => new { Shipments = x.Shipments, Audit = y })
.Select(...)
.ToList()
.GroupBy(x => new {x.TrackingNumber, x.InvoiceNumber})
.Select(z => z.FirstOrDefault())
.ToList();
```

I can't seem to get the last record to be the one I pick up from Audit.

I have tried adding `.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdatedOn)` to the `.GroupJoin` as well as the `.SelectMany` with no affect.

This is the query that I am trying to reproduce in LINQ:

`SELECT ship.Invoice_Number, au.Notes, au2.date_added 
FROM shipments ship 
LEFT OUTER JOIN audit au ON ship.Invoice_Number = au.invoice_number AND au.is_manual_note = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN audit au2 ON ship.Invoice_Number = au2.invoice_number AND ra2.notes = 'Auto Created' AND au2.date_added = (SELECT MAX(date_added) FROM audit WHERE Invoice_Number = ship.invoice_number AND notes = 'Auto Created')`

The audit table has to be joined twice, once to pull the manually entered notes and once to determine when the audit was created. The date_added query is necessary since shipments can move in and out of audit multiple times.

Sammer